# A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice Message: Undefined property: stdClass::$moderator_id, using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

hey guys i am new in codeigniter and am working on an application in which i have to fecth data from mysql database,for this purpose i make two views for and two functions in controller to handle views . . the problem is that i got error in one view while in the other view its work fine . . . both view has same code. . . where is the mistake pls help . .

code in both  views

```
 <?php foreach ($rows as $row):?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo anchor("Home/edit_moderator/" . $row->member_id, 'Edit'); ?></td>
                <td><a href="<?php echo site_url("dbcont/deletemoderator/" . $row->member_id);?>" onclick="return confirm('Delete content?');">Delete</a></td>
                <td><?php echo $row->member_name;  ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row->moderator_id;  ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row->kcc_branch;  ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row->father_name;  ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row->address;  ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row->date;  ?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
```

the error is in when i fetch  `moderator_id`

```
<td><?php echo $row->moderator_id;  ?></td>
```

in the first view it fetched but in second view it doesn't . .

EDIT :

Here is the model

```
function get_moderators(){ 

    $select =   array(
                    'member_id', 
                    'member_name', 
                    'father_name', 
                    'date', 
                    'kcc_branch', 
                    'date_of_birth', 
                    'address', 
                    'phone', 
                    'mobile', 
                    'occupation', 
                    'pan', 
                    'bank_name', 
                    'bank_acc_no', 
                    'bank_branch', 'moderator'
    );

$this->db->select($select); 
$this->db->where('moderator', 1); 
$q = $this->db->get('tbl_members'); 
    if($q->num_rows() > 0) { 
        foreach ($q->result() as $row) { 
            $data[] = $row; 
        }
        return $data; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Did you mean to use `$row->member_id`

Comment: @Martin :- no,i want to fetch `moderator_id` on view . .

Comment: How did you passed $rows to both the views from controller?

Comment: @Jay but you use `member_id` when referencing edit, and delete `moderator`.. it'd make sense to use `moderator_id` there too logically? In any case, there's no issue with this code in itself - you need to see what keys are getting pushed into `$rows`.

Comment: @Martin :- my controller code is `function moderate()
 {
   $this->load->model('user');
   $data['rows'] = $this->user->get_moderators();
   $this->load->view('moderator_view',$data);
  }`

Comment: @Jay what is `get_moderators` and check the contents of `print_r($data['rows'])` (or `$rows` in your view).

Comment: show your model function where you are querying.

Comment: on first view i fetch data member but on second view i fetch moderator.on second view only `$row->member_id` gives error while other data are fetched @Martin

Comment: @Martin :- my model  is                                             `function get_moderators()
 {
  $this->db->select('member_id, member_name, father_name, date, kcc_branch, date_of_birth, address, phone, mobile, occupation, pan, bank_name, bank_acc_no, bank_branch, moderator');
  $this->db->where('moderator', 1);
  $q = $this->db->get('tbl_members');
  if($q->num_rows() > 0)
  {
            foreach ($q->result() as $row) {
                $data[] = $row;
            }

            return $data;
        }
 }`

Comment: @raheelshan:- see my model in above comment . .

Comment: @Jay add it to your question, not in comments

Comment: do you have a `moderator_id` column on your database?

Comment: i got my answer  . . thanx to all . .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got my answer  . . my mistake is i am not selecting moderator_id in select query . .here is the answer thanx for answering guys . .

```
function get_moderators(){ 

$select =   array(
                'member_id',
                'moderator_id', 
                'member_name', 
                'father_name', 
                'date', 
                'kcc_branch', 
                'date_of_birth', 
                'address', 
                'phone', 
                'mobile', 
                'occupation', 
                'pan', 
                'bank_name', 
                'bank_acc_no', 
                'bank_branch', 'moderator'
);


$this->db->select($select); 
$this->db->where('moderator', 1); 
$q = $this->db->get('tbl_members'); 
if($q->num_rows() > 0) { 
    foreach ($q->result() as $row) { 
        $data[] = $row; 
    }
    return $data; 
} 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get rid of the select array and just use

> $this->db->select('*');

should work as well

I had a similar error and it turned out that my database select statement was wrong.
this was the bad one:

> $this->db->select('field1', 'field2', 'field3', 'field4'); //bad code

this is the right way to do it:

> $this->db->select('field1, field2, field3, field4'); //good

or

> $this->db->select('*'); //still good

best regards